# Unable to load script object from the window object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to load the three-dxf script into my React app using below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/dist/three-dxf.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => scriptLoaded();

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); //also tried document.head and document.body
});
```

The above does not give any error, however, inside the scriptLoaded function, when I try to load the ThreeDxf object from the window object, it gives undefined, i.e.

`window.ThreeDxf.Viewer(...)` gives an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'Viewer' of undefined**

Any idea why the window object does not contain ThreeDxf?

Comment: @dMd Tried. No difference.

Comment: yeah i was curious; ran into an issue before where it does not execute the script; do you see it injecting in the head?

Comment: @dMd Yes, I do see the script injected in the head, as

<script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" src="/dist/three-dxf.js" async=""></script>

However, cannot retrieve the ThreeDxf object from the window object.

Comment: Thanks @dmd I have been able to use the dxfParser, however, it is the viewer which does not work. I am using a library at https://github.com/gdsestimating/three-dxf. In its sample, which is vanilla JS, they import their library as a <script> in index.html and I am trying to import it in React using useEffect. But the problem above presents.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dynamically creating the element, you will get no error (I guess, from webpack) until the scriptLoaded() is executed. Make sure the src path is correct. Note that dist folder is, in general, the output folder for webpack, if you are running your bundle inside dist folder, you should't specific that folder in your path. Of course, it could change according to your webpack configuration.
In less words, make sure you link your "original" file and not the one inside dist folder.

Comment: The script files are part of this library at -- https://github.com/gdsestimating/three-dxf/tree/master/src

I included them in my project in a folder called threedxf and referred to them in their non bundled form as

script.src = "./threedxf/index.js";

However, the error persists and still window.ThreeDxf is undefined.

Comment: Actually, it worked! I imported the module exports from that source directly without linking them as external script. Thanks.

Still the approach to linking didn't work hence original question is unresolved, but workaround of importing them as module imports resolved the issue in this case.

Comment: Note that you have a point in the path, script.src shouldn't have a single point because it isn't manage by react library. The question here is where is the three-dxf.js file (or three-dxf/index.js) and the location of the component with that useEffect?